# I am not able to view this login page?

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, flask, wsgi

I am trying to make a login page using flask and python but I amnot able to be routed to that page it is directly going to return statement and printing Hello in my case. If I try adding else case it is going into else case and doing things in else case.And if I put main function in else case it is giving error :

werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'Employee_ID'

code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "127.1.1.0"
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = "***"
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] ="users"

mysql = MySQL(app)
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userDetails = request.form
        Employee_ID = userDetails['Employee_ID']
        password = userDetails['password']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from user where Employee_ID=%s",(Employee_ID))
        EmpDetails=cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
        if EmpDetails== password:
            flash('You have logged in successfully !!')
            return 0
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML Template:

```
</head>
<h1><center>Sign In!</center></h1>

<body>

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form" >
<form class="register-form" method="post" action="login.html">
    <input type="text" id="Employee_ID" placeholder="Employee ID" />
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>

    <button>Enter</button>
        </form>
    </div>    

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I am planning for production.Please let me know how to get rid of injection issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **name** field in the html inputs. The form elements are fetched using the input name field. You are trying to get the element values using the `id` field due to which the **KeyError** is being raised, as no element in the form with that key is being found.

Change your HTML file as:

```
</head>
<h1><center>Sign In!</center></h1>

<body>

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form" >
<form class="register-form" method="post" action="login.html">
    <input type="text" id="Employee_ID" name="Employee_ID" placeholder="Employee ID" /> <-- add name field
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/> <--add name field

    <button>Enter</button>
        </form>
    </div>    

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong wtith html code to run a python function and you need to define in html form to trigger your action like this..

Corrected solution:

```
<form class="register-form" method="post" action="/login">
<input type="text" id="Employee_ID" placeholder="Employee ID" />
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```